# When to use $\Sigma_1^0$ induction

Tags: logic

In the book 'Subsystems of Second Order Arithmetic' by Simpson, chapter $2$, page $67$, Lemma $II.2.4$

Given $k$, there exists $m>0$ such that $\forall i < k (i+1$ divides $m)$

In the proof, it states that 'it can be easily proved by $\Sigma_1^0$ induction on $k$.'

Question: Why is it $\Sigma_1^0$ induction? I thought it should be $\Pi_1^0$?

Comment: `\sum` is a different command than `\Sigma`, and `\prod` is a different command than `\Pi`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement being proved by induction is a $\Pi^0_2$ sentence:
$$
(\forall k)(\exists m > 0)(\forall i < k)(\exists s < m+1)[(i+1)\cdot(s) = m]
$$
To prove this, we first let $k$ be fixed. This gives a $\Sigma^0_1$ formula with free variable $k$:
$$
\phi(k) \equiv (\exists m > 0)(\forall i < k)(\exists s < m+1)[(i+1)\cdot(s) = m]
$$
That formula is then proved by induction on $k$.

Separately, the scheme of $\Pi^0_1$ induction is provable from $\mathsf{RCA}_0$, which includes only $\Sigma^0_1$ induction as an axiom scheme. So, even if $\phi$ was $\Pi^0_1$, it would be OK. But in this case, $\phi$ really is $\Sigma^0_1$.

Comment: $\phi$ is $\Sigma_1^0$ is due to the quantifier $\exists m \theta$ and $\theta$ is $\Sigma_0^0$?

Comment: More or less; there are various definitions of what $\Sigma^0_0$ means. But everyone would agree that $\theta$ has only bounded quantifiers, which means $(\exists m)\theta$ is $\Sigma^0_1$.